# Trying to get a record set containing all the files of the people you follow

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to make a small function to a website that I'm creating that let's you follow other users and then your dashboard fills up with the files they upload in that order of upload date. (You can compare it to youtube. You subscribe to a channel and on the subscriptions page you see every video in order by date of people you follow).

This is my model structure (It is simplified to only show the needed values for this to work).

Follow

- my_id (This is your id)
- user_id (This is the id of the user that you're following)

User

- id (The user id)

Files

- user_id (The id of the user who uploaded the file)
- path (file path)

I have tried many things now to get the data:

```php
Follow::where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()->all()->files;  
Follow::where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()->files;
```

The only thing that seems to work is (But this is only for 1 follow):

```php
Follow::where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first()->files;
```

It would be amazing if someone could see what I'm doing wrong.
In my `Follow.php` model I have it connected like this.

```php
class Follow extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'me_id'];

    public function me()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'me_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\File', //The model I'm trying to reach
            'App\User', //The model I need to go through to reach the files
            'id', //This is where I'm going wrong I think
            'user_id', //Same here
            'user_id', //Same here
            'id' //Same here
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I have it working doing 2 seperate database calls. But is this possible in a single call. See code underneath.

```
public function following(Request $request)
    {
        $follows = Follow::where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()->all();
        $userIds = [];

        foreach($follows as $key => $follow) {
            $userIds[] = $follow->user_id;
        }
        $files = File::where('visible', '=', '1')->whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(12)->onEachSide(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model definition is ok since you can get files using:

```php
Follow::where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first()->files;
```

#### Your mistake

The following code returns a [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections):

```php
Follow::where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()
```

The following code returns an array:

```php
Follow::where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()->all()
```

And `files` is a dynamic property of `Follow` model (Not collection nor array).
So this is not gonna work as you expect.

#### Your right solution

You should use eloquent [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) feature:

```php
Follow::with('files')->where('me_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get()
```

This returns a collection of `Follow` containing all their respective `files`. like:

```php
[
    'my_id' -> 1,
    'user_id' -> 1,
    'files' -> [
        'user_id' -> 1,
        'path' -> '/foo/bar'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Okay this seems like the right path! Would it be at all possible to sort all the files on "created_at"? So not sorted at upload date per follow. But 1 sorting for all the files in the record set? Sorry for the really bad explanation. I don't know how to explain this one better.

Comment: Assuming the final result is stored in `$result` as a collection, you can do this: `$result->pluck('files')->flatten()->sortByDesc('created_at')`

Comment: Thank you I'll try this. I've added a Edit to the post with a working piece of code that does 2 separate database calls. I'll try to make it 1 with your suggestion! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this in two steps.

1. Get the user that the user is following
2. Get the files from users with ids from the first query

Comment: If I do it that way. How can I sort all the files by their upload date. I need 1 record set of files from the people that I follow so I can order them by created_at

Comment: Laravel collections have method for sorting - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sort